# Using REPLACE AND LIKE

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I am currently trying to update a column in a temporary table using Oracle 11g SQL syntax. In this column there is an Unique ID that is 12 digits long. However I need to join this table with this column holding the Unique ID but the syntax for the Unique ID of this table is slightly different than the syntax for the table that it will be joined (with Unique ID serving as the PK = FK). This may be tough to follow so I will provide what I am doing below.

UniqueID Column from TABLE xyz Syntax
AB10783421111111

UniqueID Column from TABLE zxo Syntax
383421111111

You see how the numbers are identical except for the AB107 and first '3' in the zxo table? I would like to know why both these queries are not running

```
UPDATE temp37 SET UNIQUE_ID = REPLACE(UNIQUE_ID, (LIKE 'AB107%'), (LIKE '3%'));

UPDATE temp37
SET UNIQUE_ID = '3%'
WHERE UNIQUE_ID = 'AB107%';
```

Essentially I would like to replace every case of an id with AB10755555555555 to 355555555555. Thank you for any help.

Comment: The first has syntax errors.  The second is using `LIKE` patterns with `=`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
UPDATE temp37 SET UNIQUE_ID = REPLACE(UNIQUE_ID, 'AB107', '3');
```

OR

```
UPDATE temp37 SET UNIQUE_ID = CONCAT('3', substr(UNIQUE_ID, 6)) WHERE UNIQUE_ID LIKE 'AB107%';
```